# Accessing deleted memory

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, undefined-behavior

While testing my realization of stack (that is using linked list) I found one interesting thing. There is a test code to reproduce it:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int val;
    Node *prev;
};

int main() {
    Node *first = new Node;
    first->val = 20;
    first->prev = NULL;

    cout << "first:" << first << endl;

    Node *p = new Node;
    p->val = 40;
    p->prev = first;

    delete p;

    cout << "p->val:" << p->val << endl;
    cout << "p->prev:" << p->prev << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
first:0x22cfc20
p->val:0
p->prev:0x22cfc20
```

But if I swap the order of elements in the definition of `struct Node` like this:

```
struct Node {
    Node *prev;
    int val;
};
```

output will be

```
first:0x195dc20
p->val:40
p->prev:0
```

Of course it's undefined behavior in both cases but maybe it exist some rational explanation why it works this way? Or it's just random? I tried to run the code many times but it gave same output every time (except specific address value) and never crushed.

Comment: Undefined behavior isn't really _interesting_.

Comment: "Undefined behavior" means "undefined behavior". The actual behavior you've observed depends heavily on your implementation's heap management routines. And since you didn't bother to even specify your operating system, no further information can be gleaned here.

Comment: And as soon as you change compiler options (like optimizations), your program may start to behave differently.  Then you will see the futility of chasing around reasons for undefined behavior.  At some point you realize it is a waste of time and you have better things to do (like developing your application).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others state, there's very little we can definitively say about this situation not only because of the undefined behavior but also because we don't know anything about the platform it was compiled on.

But there are a few things that can be said:

Changing the order of members in the struct may cause the compiler to apply different padding between the members or at the end of the struct so as to satisfy whatever alignment rules its currently compiling with.

If that did happen in this case, then it could influence the layout of memory allocated in the heap and consequently influence what data happens to get overwritten when heap space is deallocated and then reused. This could potentially explain why the results are different.

Answer (score 2):

Undefined behavior simply don't specify any specific behavior *at all*. An implementation could be permitted to make your program work, or  to shutdown your computer, format your hard drive, open a black hole inside your cat, and even open a cat inside your black hole.

Most implementation will halt the execution if the program is trying to do invalid operation on memory. Sometime, if you're unlucky, your program will work just fine, just like your example did.

With that said: There is hundreds of reasons why you might be able to access deleted memory, but any assumption about the behavior of doing so are invalid and may lay to different result for any reason.